# Serialization or SQlite?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, serialization

I'm making a patient database program using Visual C#. It will have forms and will consist of 3 tabs with information about the patient. It will also have add, save, previous, next buttons and a search function. The most important thing is each record will have like 60 items/columns/attributes per record and the records could reach to 50k-100k or more.

Now my question is, which is better for my program? Should I use SQlite or Serialization/Deserialization?

Thanks

Comment: Hint: quick question: if you used serialisation, where would you put the files? How would you search them? How quick do you think it would be?

Comment: dunno know much about serializaton really. i will just read about it if it's better to use it over database. but i want the backup files to be in the same computer as the program.

Answer (score 2):

The "database" word in the question strongly suggests that *just* serialization/deserialization isn't enough. Of course if you can fit all of your data into memory and you're happy to perform all the querying yourself, it could work - but you'll need to consider the cost of potentially reading everything into memory on startup, and possibly writing everything out whenever you change anything.

A database does sound like a better fit to me, to be honest. Whether SQLite is the most appropriate database for you or not is a different question though.

Having said all of this, for the C# in Depth website I keep all the information about comments / errata in a simple XML file, which is loaded lazily and saved every time I make a change. It works well, it's easy to manage, and the file is human readable in source control when I want it. However, I have *vastly* fewer records than you, and they're much simpler too. I don't have any search requirements - I just need to list everything and fetch by ID. My guess is that your needs are rather more complex, hence my recommendation to use a database.

Comment: well, I just want to be able to have a backup file with all the records in it just in case something wrong happens in the future. i don't know much about serialization other than some peeps recommending me that over database since they said it's "overkill".

Comment: @Levi: Any database worth speaking about will have ways of backing it up. You haven't really told us anything about requirements beyond how many records and how many fields - not even how much data is in each field. Do you need to do any searching, for example? Have you estimated the total *size* of data, and worked out whether it's realistic to have all of that in memory in your app at once?

Comment: what do you mean how much data in each field? i think only one per field it's mostly number specifics of the patient's eyeglasses etc.. i forgot to say it's for an optical shop. also i will search using filter like '%' + @name '%' something simple like that.

Comment: btw i want the program to have textfields instead of the database itself so it's easy for my friend to use the program. I mean so it's organized and on different tabs.

Comment: @Levi: By "how much data in each field" I mean will you have images, large text fields etc, or is it just single word fields? As for the UI - that's completely separate from the storage mechanism.

Comment: yea it's just words or numbers except for some fields such as address, notes and eyeglasses specifics which are few.

Comment: Definitely use the SQLite. I can't see any strong advantage in serialization in this scenario. Don't forget that SQLite is more robust and has atomic transactions, almost no data corruption is possible - not even in case of power failure. And the size of records may grow by time or you will need more complex queries...